# Shopware Modify Shoppingworld Element configuration data for front-end

Tags: php, class, plugins, event-handling, shopware

I'm on my way to develop a Shopware 5 Shoppingworld Element.
My plan is that the user can choose a category from a dropdown box.
This works fine so far. I generate the Dropdown box with the following code:

```
        $vimeoElement->createComboBoxField([
        'name' => 'category_selection',
        'fieldLabel' => 'Kategorie-Auswahl',
        'allowBlank' => true,
        'valueField' => 'id',
        'displayField' => 'name',
        'store' => 'Shopware.apps.Emotion.store.CategoryPath',
    ]);
```

My Problem is, that I need all Information about this category (link, description etc.) in my front-end template but I only get the id.

I searched in the shopware documentation and found out that I need to use a ComponentHandler to prepare my datas before it would be passed to the front-end.

I followed this Tutorial: https://developers.shopware.com/developers-guide/custom-shopping-world-elements/#process-the-element-data-before-output

I created a file in `/custom/plugins/MyPluginName/ComponentHandler/VimeoComponentHandler.php`

And added the following code:

```
<?php

namespace MyPluginName\ComponentHandler;


class VimeoComponentHandler implements ComponentHandlerInterface
{
    public function supports(Element $element)
    {
        return true; 
       // return $element->getComponent()->getTemplate() === 'emotion_vimeo';
    }

    public function prepare(PrepareDataCollection $collection, Element $element, ShopContextInterface $context)
    {
        // do some prepare logic, e.g. requesting articles for rendering
    }

    public function handle(ResolvedDataCollection $collection, Element $element, ShopContextInterface $context)
    {
        // do some handle logic and fill the element data, which will be available in your template
        $element->getData()->set('key', 'value');
    }
}

?>
```

Finally I added this lines to /custom/plugins/MyPluginName/Resources/services.xml:

```
<service id="swag_vimeo_element.vimeo_component_handler" class="MyPluginName\ComponentHandler\VimeoComponentHandler">
    <tag name="shopware_emotion.component_handler"/>
</service>
```

Now it seems like that my front-end should get a new variable. But it didn't.

In my Apache logs I can see the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Interface 'MyPluginName\\ComponentHandler\\ComponentHandlerInterface' not found in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\custom\\plugins\\MyPluginName\\ComponentHandler\\VimeoComponentHandler.php on line 6, referer: http://192.168.3.64/
```

I need to get all information about a category in a front-end template. I only got the category Id.

Answer (score 2):

In your `VimeoComponentHandler`, it looks like you forgot to import the `ComponentHandlerInterface`:

```
<?php

namespace MyPluginName\ComponentHandler;

// Add following line
use Shopware\Bundle\EmotionBundle\ComponentHandler\ComponentHandlerInterface;


class VimeoComponentHandler implements ComponentHandlerInterface
{
    // ... 
}

?>
```